# cakephp autoFields container behavior to false doesn't show any row

Tags: cakephp

I have a model of a person that contains books:

```
<?php
    class Person extends AppModel{
    var $name = "Person";
    var $hasMany = array("Book");
?>
```

Book model contains book name and edition (and person_id as foreign key). I want to find all the persons of my data base and for each person show the books that he has showing only the book name and edition and not the person id. I am trying to perform it with autoFields container property. If I perform the query as follows:

```
$persons = $this -> Person -> find('all', array('order' => 'Person.id ASC', 'fields' => array('Person.id', 'Person.name'),
          'contain' => array('Book' => array('fields' => array('Book.name', 'Book.edition')))));
```

It shows all the persons with all their books with the book name, edition and person id:

```
[
   {
      Person: {
               id: "1",
               name: "Phil"
              },
      Book: [
              {
                name: "Little Red Riding Hood",
                edition: "4th",
                person_id: "1"
               },
              {
                name: "The Woman in White",
                edition: "6th",
                person_id: "1"
               }
            ]
    }
]
```

But I don't want to show the person_id inside the book properties. So I try to do it with autoFields like that:

```
$persons = $this -> Person -> find('all', array('order' => 'Person.id ASC', 'fields' => array('Person.id', 'Person.name'),
        'contain' => array('Book' => array('fields' => array('Book.name', 'Book.edition'), 'autoFields' => false))));
```

Doing that way it does not show any books:

```
[
   {
      Person: {
               id: "1",
               name: "Phil"
              },
      Book: []
    }
]
```

If I put autoFields in any other place it does the same as with the first find and shows person_id property inside Book. What am I doing wrong? Do you know where to put autoFields to get what I want? Thanks

Comment: I don't need the person_id because it is already displayed in person so it is redundant data and I need to do my data as small as possible. I can do it with sql so I have to be able to do it with cake but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you at least need to include `person_id` in the Book fields as it is the foreign key; since you do not include it, no results are found because foreign key is needed to find books of person.

Comment: Book has person_id as foreign key. If I don't use autoFields it finds the correct results but it includes the person_id in the result properties and I don't want to. If I set autoFields to false then it does not find any results. With sql I can define which columns I want to show in the results so with cake I have to be able to do it too.

Comment: As described by the book
"autoFields: (boolean, optional) auto-add needed fields to fetch requested bindings."
If you set it to false, the field responsible for the binding is not automatically included. It expects you to include it in the fields array; For clarity, do a echo $this->element(sql_dump) to see what it outputs.

Comment: What it ouptuts is in my first message in JSON format.

Comment: sql_dump to see the sql statements that are issued when you do the requests not their resulting array as you seem to say!